# Why is Photoshop CC 14.2.1 x64 saving temp files in the same location as PSDs?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I've noticed that in the past 2 weeks or so, Photoshop has been saving temp files in the same directory as PSD files, rather than in the default location (C:\Users[user]\AppData\Local\Temp) on Windows 7.

I haven't made any changes to the scratch disk settings, or other preferences. Is this normal behavior? Is it something that I need to change, or can it even be changed?

Comment: If they're just temp files, which should have unique names and which I'd expect to be destroyed on program close, does it really matter if they bunk in together with some other program's temporary files?  It could be that I don't understand the question or the significance of why you're asking.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. The problem is that the temp files are being saved in the same directory as my PSD files, rather than where they should be ("bunk[ed] in together with some other program's"). Also, they're not being destroyed when Photoshop closes. So, I'm ending up with dozens of 0k temp files littering a directory where working files are stored.

It's not really harming anything - I'm just wondering if I should be concerned about it, or if it indicates that Photoshop isn't functioning properly.

Comment: If the temp files are similar to the temp/lock files used by LibreOffice, they're created in the same directory as the actual file so that multiple instances of LibreOffice on multiple machines sharing the same set of directories for saved files won't get confused because each machine would have its own temp directory.  I'm not sure how LibreOffice stores a temporary file before the file is named and saved somewhere permanent.  Just a perspective.  Definitely not authoritative.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses. It appears that this problem has been around for a while, but has no official solution. I found these threads for reference:

https://forums.adobe.com/message/4081007

https://forums.adobe.com/message/3851270#3851270

Answer (score -1):

If you mean that when you use Save as it goes to the temp folder on your Drive if you want to stop it Saving as to the Temp folder go Edit>Preferences>File Handling look for the the Save as to Original folder and untick and Click ok it should stop going the temp folder.